# php-amqplib: How to prevent infinite loading web page?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, daemon, php-amqp

I use a cloud service to handle RabbitMQ. The purpose is to send and receive messages from smart objects that use MQTT. All works but...
**A formPage.php on submit triggers a shellexec command that executes initRpc.php.**
In initRpc.php this infinite loop is used to receive messages but block every other functions even if declared before, like an header('location ...');

```
while (count($channel->callbacks)) 
     {
       try {
           $channel->wait(null, false, $timeout);
           }
       catch (AMQPTimeoutException $e) {
           return;                
           }
      }
```

**The result is that the formPage.php on submit remain on the same page, loading for ever. How to prevent this issue?**

However I can still navigate the website clicking manually on links and make also other request..so the receiver it's running in background without problems.

Comment: Can you be more clear. Is initRpc.php the action when formPage is submitted or not?

Comment: yes initRpc.php is the action

Comment: Okey, so it is normal because the trigger itself is a part of PHP current process.To avoid this, you can use websocket to send the signal to the rabbiMQ workers

Comment: Thanks for help but can you be more specific or give me a simpler solution?

Comment: The problem is solved: i used ajax to call the script. This prevent the infinite loop loading but call remains in pending.

Comment: Have the same problem. Dont understand it. The Rabbit documentation code seems like a nonsense. I have endless script. Wau.